# Find an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb R^3$, with its usual scalar product, whose first two vectors belong to the equation plane

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

The equation plane is $x_1 + x_2 + x_3 = 0$.

$(-1,0,1)$ and $(0,1,-1)$ are on the equation plan.

I don't know if I am suppose to use Gram-Schmidt process to find the third right?

Or I am suppose to find a third vector eg: $(1,1,1)$
and use Gram-Schmidt process on the three vectors

Comment: Welcome to MSE. A question should be written in such a way that it can be understood even by someone who did not read the title.

Comment: Gram-schmidt on the two vectors will just give you two orthonormal (or orthogonal, depending on which version you use) vectors that have the same span as the first two vectors; it won't give you a third orthogonal vector. Note that $(1, 1, 1)$ is normal to the plane, so it will automatically be orthogonal to whatever vectors you get, so all it needs is to be normalised.

Answer (score 0):

Apply Gram-Schmidt to $\{(-1,0,1),(0,1,-1)\}$, normalize the vectors that you get, and you shall get an orthonormal basis of that plane, which will be
$$
\left\{\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1,0,1),\frac1{\sqrt6}(-1,2,-1)\right\}.
$$
Then,
\begin{multline}
\left\{\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1,0,1),\frac1{\sqrt6}(-1,2,-1),\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1,0,1)\times\frac1{\sqrt6}(-1,2,-1)\right\}=\\
=\left\{\frac1{\sqrt2}(-1,0,1),\frac1{\sqrt6}(-1,2,-1),\frac1{\sqrt3}(-1,-1,-1)\right\}
\end{multline}
shall be an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: No, they will be "only" ortho*gonal*.  Normalize afterwards.

Comment: @MichaelHoppe The way I was taught, normalization is part of the Gram-Schmidt process. But I have edited my answer.